# Issues with Gtk# 2.99.3

Tags: mono, gtk, gtk#

I had to install Gtk# 2.99 because I must to use the CssProvider class.
After install Gtk# 2.99.3 using the .msi installer I got these changes and some issues:

1. Now I can use the CssProvider class.
2. I needed to connect gio-sharp due to an error: **The type "GLib.Application" is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly "gio-sharp, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f" (CS0012)**
3. I got next warning: **Found conflicts between different versions of same dependent assembly (MSB3247)**
4. I got next exception: **System.MissingMethodException: "Void System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(!!0, IntPtr, Boolean)"**

How I can resolve these issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error when I use monodevelop. I found that it was because I did not tell IDE the location of the library that I used.
[error reported from monodevelop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJoN3.png)

To solve this I right-clicked on "References" and click edit reference..., then add the missing library (in my case, it was in gio-sharp (I clicked the check box), then everything is fine.
[right click on the reference tab to add the library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdhQP.png)