# How to correctly update Gtk# in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin, monodevelop, gtk#

I need to update Gtk# to version 2.99.3 in Xamarin Studio. A few days ago I tried to update it using [.msi installer](https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/releases), but after that I got [some issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705399/issues-with-gtk-2-99-3). And after deleting old version of Gtk#(before this I already installed new version) my Xamarin failed to start. Log:

> Xamarin Studio failed to start. Some of the assemblies required to run Xamarin Studio(for example gtk-sharp) may not be properly installed in the GAC. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: ...... "glib-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral...."

So I have just one question: **how to update Gtk# to the specific version in Xamarin?**

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Studio is not compatible with Gtk# version 2.99.3

Gtk# version 2.99.3 is a community produced wrapper for GTK3. Xamarin Studio requires GTK2.

Xamarin have publicly announced that they will not be moving to GTK3.